# Cannot concatenate 'str' with 'int' objects inside class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, io, int

I'm getting "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" but I've set the raw_input() as int() function before. What am I doing wrong with the functions (deposit and transaction) in my class?

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        f = open("ac.txt", "r")
        self.balance = f.read()

    def deposit(self, amt):
        f = open("ac.txt", "w")
        f.write(self.balance + amt)
        f.close()

    def withdraw(self, amt):
        pass

    def getBalance(self):
        return self.balance

    def transaction(self):
        choice = raw_input("\n1. Deposit\n2. Withdraw\n\nChoice: ")
        amount = int(raw_input("\nPlease enter your amount: "))

        if choice == "1":
            self.deposit(amount)
        elif choice == "2":
            self.withdraw(amount)
```

I even tried to do this:

```
amount = raw_input("\nPlease enter your amount: ")
amount = int(amount)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should not use `int(raw_input(...` if you want to **concatenate strings**, just use `raw_input`, otherwise you are adding an int to a string here: `f.write(self.balance + amt)`

### EDIT:

but if you wanna add digits `balance + amount`, and write back to the file, convert both `self.balance` and `amt` to numbers (`int` or `float`) as @Hugh mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If `self.balance = f.read()` then balance is a str and amount is an int, and str + int gives an error.

Try `f.write(self.balance + str(amt))` instead.

Comment: wouldnt he want `int(self.balance) + int(amt)`? (+1 all the same since this is definitely the issue)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: ... or `self.balance = int(f.read())` then `f.write(str(self.balance + amt))`; depends what he's trying to accomplish, but the types must match.

Comment: it just seems counter intuitive if his amt was `5` and his balance was `65` to write `655` into the file instead of `70` ... but I suppose theres a chance thats what he wants

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, I don't want it to merge. I want it to add and subtract with deposit and withdraw.

Answer (score 1):

In the "ac.txt" file you are writing integer as text ! That is as sequence of character. Therefore after

```
f = open("ac.txt", "r")
self.balance = f.read()
```

`self.balance` is a string. So you can't do `self.balance + amt`.

You should write

```
self.balance = int(f.read())
```

to make sure that you read some `int` and then

```
f.write(str(self.balance + amt))
```